# Archive mode in arcgis with arcobjects

Tags: arcobjects, archiving

One question to Archive mode in ArcGIS.
I am new to ArcObjects. Is there the possibility to change an archive class table with arcobjects by listening through events. Every time when I make an edit, the archive class is updated automatically but not with necessary information I want.  So if editing has stopped, a column to archive class table should have been added and filled with information like 'inserted', 'deleted'.

In generally I have an ArcGIS add-in button callling a userform when pressed.
So one class button.vb, one class form.vb
Where should I implement events overall. Events like mouseover, editingstopped or any other event from ArcObjects.

Comment: I can't speak to archive classes but for edit events you can implement either an editor extension or a class extension. This will give you access to events such as add, update, delete, start editing, stop editing  etc. I don't know of a way to access mouse over events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I understand right you are talking about the *_H tables that comes together with the ArcGIS versioning? They are a part of an internal mechanism of ArcGIS that cannot be modified directly with ArcGIS tools or ArcObjects and should not be changed with SQL because the data could get broken.

So I think the question is how to get informed about data changes. You can wire the events where you want according you development style. Attached you’ll find a c# code example. You probably can translate the code to VB better than me. You can wire the events like this:

```cs
IEditor m_Editor = ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(uid) as IEditor;
IEditEvents_Event editEvents = m_Editor as IEditEvents_Event;
if (editEvents != null)
{
      editEvents.OnCreateFeature += new IEditEvents_OnCreateFeatureEventHandler(EventListener_OnCreateFeature);
      editEvents.OnChangeFeature += new IEditEvents_OnChangeFeatureEventHandler(EventListener_OnChangeFeature);
      editEvents.OnDeleteFeature += new IEditEvents_OnDeleteFeatureEventHandler(EventListener_OnDeleteFeature);
}
```

And define the event methods like this:

```cs
private void EventListener_OnCreateFeature (object theObject)
{
}
private void EventListener_OnChangeFeature (object theObject)
{
}
private void EventListener_OnDeleteFeature (object theObject)
{
}
```

Inside the event methods you can cast the objects to an IFeature and continue:

```cs
IFeature feature = theObject as IFeature;
```

Comment: Thank you  very much, this is what i was searching for.  Great :) !!